# Can't vertically orient a SKLabelNode with anchorPoint

Tags: objective-c, rotation, sprite-kit

I want to make a text-based game using Sprite Kit (a la those Learn to Type games).

I thought I'd use SKLabelNode for strings, but when I try to set the anchorPoint in order to rotate it, I get an error that SKLabelNode doesn't have the anchorPoint property:

```
 SKLabelNode *hello = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];
 hello.text = @"Hello,";
//this throws an error:
 hello.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
```

What's a good workaround? How can I vertically orient my text strings, while treating them like physical objects using physicsBody?

Comment: offset position by half width/height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I realized I didn't need anchorPoint at all for what I was trying to achieve — instead, I used

```
hello.zRotation = M_PI/2;
```

This works for SKLabelNode.

Answer (score 16):

SKLabelNode doesn't have anchor point.

Use `verticalAlignmentMode` property to align SKLabelNode vertically.

```
SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline
```

**Positions the text so that the font’s baseline lies on the node’s origin.**

```
SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter
```

**Centers the text vertically on the node’s origin.**

```
SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeTop
```

**Positions the text so that the top of the text is on the node’s origin.**

```
SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBottom
```

**Positions the text so that the bottom of the text is on the node’s origin.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013022-CH1-SW15

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't address the question asked.  This covers vertical alignment, not orienting the text vertical  (i.e. rotated by 90 degrees).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the SKLabelNode as a child of a SKSpriteNode. Then apply the anchorPoint
(and rotation etc) to the parent node:

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)testNode {
SKSpriteNode *testNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];//parent
SKLabelNode *hello = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];//child
hello.text = @"Hello,";
[testNode addChild:hello];
testNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
testNode.position=CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);
return testNode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would tackle your problem

```
    SKLabelNode *labNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
    labNode.fontSize = 30.0f;
    labNode.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
    labNode.text = @"TEST";

    SKTexture *texture;
    SKView *textureView = [SKView new];
    texture = [textureView textureFromNode:labNode];
    texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKSpriteNode *spriteText = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
    //spriteText.position = put me someplace good;

    [self addChild:spriteText];
```

Comment: Stopped crashing if I replaced the skview with the current one of the current scene. However, the end sprite size always turn out 0,0 so I guess it's not grabbing the texture correct. Any reason?